# Un-indentation in Netbeans

Tags: ide, netbeans

In netbeans, if I select some text and press `Tab`, it works correctly and the text is indented to the right side as expected.

But if I then try to backspace behind the text, it only removes one space at a time. Very annoying.

Is there any way to change this setting, so backspacing behind a tabbed line causes the whole tab to be removed and not just 1 space?

Comment: I think your expectation is wrong. Please check your editor settings.

Have a look at "Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting". When "Expand Tabs to Spaces" to checked, then pressing TAB will creates several spaces and you press BACKSPACE to remove such a "tab" then only one space will be removed.

Comment: Seems still no way at this moment.  I agree with the OP that it's very annoying, even there is a Shift-Tab to do so.  IMO, Backspace to Un-Indent (at a line's indentation area) is a MUST-have for convenience for programming style which uses spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't use Netbeans (anymore), but usually the shortcut for this is Shift+Tab.

Comment: Thanks, I've wondered about this before (but not enough to actually hunt for an answer).

Comment: @Aistina  Why you are not using Netbeans anymore? Is there any problem with Netbeans? Please reply

Comment: @Muhammad this was 7 years ago, but if I remember correctly it was slowness that caused me to switch editors most of all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will you suggest me any good IDE for PHP? Thanks again

Comment: @Muhammad I personally use Sublime Text, but if you want an IDE I think the general consensus is that you can't beat PhpStorm.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text, Netbeans and I also tried PHPStorm but the the problem with Netbeans and PHPStorm is that it cannot open a project from our local development server. I have to drag and drop the project from the local shared folder. while sublime works nice and it keeps remember the project when I open it again.

Answer (score 6):

Its worth mentioning that **ALT+SHIFT+UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT** will indent left or right and also allow you to move the line(s) up or down. Its a pretty handy feature.

Comment: I knew about up down but not left right hehe, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Alt-Shift-F` (Formatting code) also can be helpful.
Select code block which needs re-indentation and do `Alt-Shift-F`.